# Build failed with an exception : Peer not authenticated

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

While Clean & build, following error comes up

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyProject'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1.
     Required by:
         :MyProject:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/1.3.0-beta1/google-services-1.3.0-beta1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/1.3.0-beta1/google-services-1.3.0-beta1.pom'.
               > peer not authenticated
      > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/1.3.0-beta1/google-services-1.3.0-beta1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/1.3.0-beta1/google-services-1.3.0-beta1.pom'.
               > peer not authenticated
```

i also added security cert in the C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\security, but still no clue how to fix it, Please help me

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
        repositories { mavenCentral() }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
          maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }

        jcenter {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why did you include mavencentral as a repository? You can remvove         repositories { mavenCentral() }

Comment: Tried but not working @babadada

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your build.gradle to this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

or force gradle to use http with this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com" }
    }
}
```